# Transform a matrix to a stacked vector where all zeroes after the last non-zero value per row are removed

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

I have a matrix with some zero values I want to erase.

```
a=[ 1 2 3 0 0; 1 0 1 3 2; 0 1 2 5 0]

>>a =

 1     2     3     0     0
 1     0     1     3     2
 0     1     2     5     0
```

However, I want to erase only the ones after the last non-zero value of each line.
This means that I want to retain `1 2 3` from the first line, `1 0 1 3 2` from the second and `0 1 2 5` from the third.

I want to then store the remaining values in a vector. In the case of the example this would result in the vector

```
b=[1 2 3 1 0 1 3 2 0 1 2 5]
```

The only way I figured out involves a `for` loop that I would like to avoid:

```
b=[];
for ii=1:size(a,1)
    l=max(find(a(ii,:)));
    b=[b a(ii,1:l)];
end
```

Is there a way to vectorize this code?

Comment: I've edited your title to make it more descriptive for your particular problem.  Making the title of your post "how can I vectorize this code" is not meaningful and it doesn't help anyone.  If someone else comes this way and sees what the title is who may have the same problem, this will certainly help.  I've also edited your post for general grammar fixes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many possible ways to do this, here is my approach:

```
 arotate = a' %//rotate the matrix a by 90 degrees
 b=flipud(arotate)  %//flips the matrix up and down
 c= flipud(cumsum(b,1)) %//cumulative sum the matrix rows -and then flip it back.
 arotate(c==0)=[] 

 arotate =

  1     2     3     1     0     1     3     2     0     1     2     5
```

=========================EDIT=====================

just realized cumsum can have direction parameter so this should do:

```
 arotate = a'
 b = cumsum(arotate,1,'reverse')
 arotate(b==0)=[]
```

This direction parameter was not available on my 2010b version, but should be there for you if you are using 2013a or above.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an approach using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)'s masking capability -

```
M = size(a,2); %// Save size parameter
at = a.'; %// Transpose input array, to be used for masked extraction

%// Index IDs of last non-zero for each row when looking from right side
[~,idx] = max(fliplr(a~=0),[],2);

%// Create a mask of elements that are to be picked up in a
%// transposed version of the input array using BSXFUN's broadcasting
out = at(bsxfun(@le,(1:M)',M+1-idx'))
```

Sample run (to showcase mask usage) -

```
>> a
a =
     1     2     3     0     0
     1     0     1     3     2
     0     1     2     5     0
>> M = size(a,2);
>> at = a.'; 
>> [~,idx] = max(fliplr(a~=0),[],2);
>> bsxfun(@le,(1:M)',M+1-idx') %// mask to be used on transposed version
ans =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     0     1     1
     0     1     0
>> at(bsxfun(@le,(1:M)',M+1-idx')).'
ans =
     1     2     3     1     0     1     3     2     0     1     2     5
```

Comment: Divakar, you can actually stop using `%//` now :).  Basic MATLAB highlighting has now been introduced so just doing `%` will render comments properly.  No need to do `%.'` if you're doing the transpose as the last statement!

Comment: @rayryeng wow, yeah I sort of noticed that something was off haha. Lovely! Thanks for letting me know that :)

Comment: Is the mixing of `'` and `.'` intentional? I see that you do it every time you know a matrix contains integers (i.e. sizes and indices).

Comment: @StewieGriffin Well spotted and yes that's intentional in all my posts, that's basically the reason because I am sure sizes can't be complex and also a bit of code-golfy mindset :)